# Tuning GLMNET using mlr3

Tags: r, mlr3

MLR3 is really cool. I am trying to tune the regularisation prarameter

```
searchspace_glmnet_trafo = ParamSet$new(list(
  ParamDbl$new("regr.glmnet.lambda", log(0.01), log(10))
))
searchspace_glmnet_trafo$trafo = function(x, param_set) {
  x$regr.glmnet.lambda = (exp(x$regr.glmnet.lambda))
  x
}
```

but get the error

> Error in glmnet::cv.glmnet(x = data, y = target, family = "gaussian",  :
> Need more than one value of lambda for cv.glmnet

A minimum non-working example is below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(mlr3verse)
data("kc_housing", package = "mlr3data")

library(anytime)
dates = anytime(kc_housing$date)
kc_housing$date = as.numeric(difftime(dates, min(dates), units = "days"))
kc_housing$zipcode = as.factor(kc_housing$zipcode)
kc_housing$renovated = as.numeric(!is.na(kc_housing$yr_renovated))
kc_housing$has_basement = as.numeric(!is.na(kc_housing$sqft_basement))

kc_housing$id = NULL
kc_housing$price = kc_housing$price / 1000
kc_housing$yr_renovated = NULL
kc_housing$sqft_basement = NULL
lrnglm=lrn("regr.glmnet")
kc_housing
tsk = TaskRegr$new("sales", kc_housing, target = "price")
fencoder = po("encode", method = "treatment",
              affect_columns = selector_type("factor"))
pipe = fencoder %>>% lrnglm

glearner = GraphLearner$new(pipe)
glearner$train(tsk)


searchspace_glmnet_trafo = ParamSet$new(list(
  ParamDbl$new("regr.glmnet.lambda", log(0.01), log(10))
))
searchspace_glmnet_trafo$trafo = function(x, param_set) {
  x$regr.glmnet.lambda = (exp(x$regr.glmnet.lambda))
  x
}
inst = TuningInstance$new(
  tsk, glearner,
  rsmp("cv"), msr("regr.mse"),
  searchspace_glmnet_trafo, term("evals", n_evals = 100)
)
gsearch = tnr("grid_search", resolution = 100)
gsearch$tune(inst)
```

Comment: Did my answer help you or did you solve your problem differently?

Answer (score 2):

`lambda` needs to be a vector param, not a single value (as the message tells).

I suggest to not tune `cv.glmnet`.
This algorithm does an internal 10-fold CV optimization and relies on its own sequence for `lambda`. 
Consult the help page of the learner for more information.

You can apply your own tuning (tuning of param `s`, not `lambda`) on `glmnet::glmnet()`. However, this algorithm is not (yet) available for use with {mlr3}.

Comment: Thank you for yor comment and making `glmnet::glmnet()` now available in {mlr3}. I have a question related to this topic: [how to repeat hyperparameter tuning (alpha and/or lambda) of glmnet in mlr3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696405/how-to-repeat-hyperparameter-tuning-alpha-and-or-lambda-of-glmnet-in-mlr3?). If you found time to look at it I would be very thankful.