# Two-level stacked learner (enseble model) combining elastic net and logistic regression using mlr3

Tags: r, machine-learning, ensemble-learning, mlr3

I try to solve a common problem in medicine: the *combination of a prediction model with other sources, eg, an expert opinion [sometimes heavily emphysised in medicine]*, called `superdoc` predictor in this post.

This could be solved by stack a model with a logistic regression (that enters the expert opinion) as described on page 26 in this paper:

> Afshar P, Mohammadi A, Plataniotis KN, Oikonomou A, Benali H. From
> Handcrafted to Deep-Learning-Based Cancer Radiomics: Challenges and
> Opportunities. IEEE Signal Process Mag 2019; 36: 132–60. Available [here](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019ISPM...36..132A/abstract)

I've tried this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66621119/building-a-nested-logistic-regression-model-using-caret-glmnet-and-a-nested-c/66643113#66643113) without considering overfitting (I did not apply out of fold predictions of the lower learner):

**Example data**

```
# library
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(mlbench)

# get example data
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes, package="mlbench")
data <- PimaIndiansDiabetes

# add the super doctors opinion to the data
set.seed(2323)
data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(superdoc=case_when(diabetes=="pos" ~ as.numeric(sample(0:2,1)), TRUE~ 0)) -> data

# separate the data in a training set and test set
train.data <- data[1:550,]
test.data <- data[551:768,]
```

**Stacked models without considering out of fold predictions:**

```
# elastic net regression (without the superdoc's opinion)
set.seed(2323)
model <- train(
  diabetes ~., data = train.data %>% select(-superdoc), method = "glmnet",
  trControl = trainControl("repeatedcv",
                           number = 10,
                           repeats=10,
                           classProbs = TRUE,
                           savePredictions = TRUE,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary),
  tuneLength = 10,
  metric="ROC" #ROC metric is in twoClassSummary
)


# extract the coefficients for the best alpha and lambda  
coef(model$finalModel, model$finalModel$lambdaOpt) -> coeffs
tidy(coeffs) %>% tibble() -> coeffs

coef.interc = coeffs %>% filter(row=="(Intercept)") %>% pull(value)
coef.pregnant = coeffs %>% filter(row=="pregnant") %>% pull(value)
coef.glucose = coeffs %>% filter(row=="glucose") %>% pull(value)
coef.pressure = coeffs %>% filter(row=="pressure") %>% pull(value)
coef.mass = coeffs %>% filter(row=="mass") %>% pull(value)
coef.pedigree = coeffs %>% filter(row=="pedigree") %>% pull(value)
coef.age = coeffs %>% filter(row=="age") %>% pull(value)


# combine the model with the superdoc's opinion in a logistic regression model
finalmodel = glm(diabetes ~ superdoc + I(coef.interc + coef.pregnant*pregnant + coef.glucose*glucose + coef.pressure*pressure + coef.mass*mass + coef.pedigree*pedigree + coef.age*age),family=binomial, data=train.data)


# make predictions on the test data
predict(finalmodel,test.data, type="response") -> predictions


# check the AUC of the model in the test data
roc(test.data$diabetes,predictions, ci=TRUE) 
#> Setting levels: control = neg, case = pos
#> Setting direction: controls < cases
#> 
#> Call:
#> roc.default(response = test.data$diabetes, predictor = predictions,     ci = TRUE)
#> 
#> Data: predictions in 145 controls (test.data$diabetes neg) < 73 cases (test.data$diabetes pos).
#> Area under the curve: 0.9345
#> 95% CI: 0.8969-0.9721 (DeLong)
```

**Now I would like to consider out of fold predictions using the `mlr3` package family according to this very helpful post: [Tuning a stacked learner](https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/posts/2020-04-27-tuning-stacking/)**

```r
#library
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3filters)
library(mlr3tuning)
library(paradox)
library(glmnet)

# creat elastic net regression
glmnet_lrn =  lrn("classif.cv_glmnet", predict_type = "prob")

# create the learner out-of-bag predictions
glmnet_cv1 = po("learner_cv", glmnet_lrn, id = "glmnet") #I could not find a setting to filter the predictors (ie, not send the superdoc predictor here)

# summarize steps 
level0 = gunion(list(
  glmnet_cv1,
  po("nop", id = "only_superdoc_predictor")))  %>>% #I could not find a setting to send only the superdoc predictor to "union1"
  po("featureunion", id = "union1")


# final logistic regression
log_reg_lrn = lrn("classif.log_reg", predict_type = "prob")

# combine ensemble model
ensemble = level0 %>>% log_reg_lrn
ensemble$plot(html = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

### My question (I am rather new to the `mlr3` package family)

1. is the `mlr3` package family well suited for the ensemble model I try to build?
2. if yes, how cold I finalize the ensemle model and make predictions on the `test.data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `mlr3` / `mlr3pipelines` is well suited for your task. It appears that what you are missing is mainly the [`PipeOpSelect` / `po("select")`](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_pipeops_select.html), which lets you extract features based on their name or other properties and makes use of [`Selector`](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/reference/Selector.html) objects. Your code should probably look something like

```
library("mlr3")
library("mlr3pipelines")
library("mlr3learners")

# creat elastic net regression
glmnet_lrn = lrn("classif.cv_glmnet", predict_type = "prob")

# create the learner out-of-bag predictions
glmnet_cv1 = po("learner_cv", glmnet_lrn, id = "glmnet")

# PipeOp that drops 'superdoc', i.e. selects all except 'superdoc'
# (ID given to avoid ID clash with other selector)
drop_superdoc = po("select", id = "drop.superdoc",
  selector = selector_invert(selector_name("superdoc")))

# PipeOp that selects 'superdoc' (and drops all other columns)
select_superdoc = po("select", id = "select.superdoc",
  selector = selector_name("superdoc"))

# superdoc along one path, the fitted model along the other
stacking_layer = gunion(list(
  select_superdoc,
  drop_superdoc %>>% glmnet_cv1
)) %>>% po("featureunion", id = "union1")

# final logistic regression
log_reg_lrn = lrn("classif.log_reg", predict_type = "prob")

# combine ensemble model
ensemble = stacking_layer %>>% log_reg_lrn
```

This is what it looks like:

```
ensemble$plot(html = FALSE)
```

[image: The stacking graph.]

To train and evaluate the model, we need to create [`Task`](https://mlr3.mlr-org.com/reference/TaskClassif.html) objects:

```
train.task <- TaskClassif$new("train.data", train.data, target = "diabetes")
test.task <- TaskClassif$new("test.data", test.data, target = "diabetes")
```

The model can now be trained, can then be used for prediction, and the quality of the prediction can be evaluated. This works best if we turn the `ensemble` into a `Learner`:

```
elearner = as_learner(ensemble)
# Train the Learner:
elearner$train(train.task)
# (The training may give a warning because the glm gets the colinear features:
# The positive and the negative probabilities)
```

Get the prediction on the test set:

```
prediction = elearner$predict(test.task)
print(prediction)
#> <PredictionClassif> for 218 observations:
#>     row_ids truth response  prob.neg   prob.pos
#>           1   neg      neg 0.9417067 0.05829330
#>           2   neg      neg 0.9546343 0.04536566
#>           3   neg      neg 0.9152019 0.08479810
#> ---                                            
#>         216   neg      neg 0.9147406 0.08525943
#>         217   pos      neg 0.9078216 0.09217836
#>         218   neg      neg 0.9578515 0.04214854
```

The prediction was made on a `Task`, so it can be used directly measure performance against ground truth, e.g. using the `"classif.auc"` [`Measure`](https://mlr3.mlr-org.com/reference/Measure.html):

```
msr("classif.auc")$score(prediction)
#> [1] 0.9308455
```

Two notes here:

1. You have split up your data into training and test set manually. `mlr3` gives you the possibility to do [resampling](https://mlr3.mlr-org.com/reference/resample.html) automatically, based on a single `Task` object. This can then go beyond simple train-test splits. Using the `data` from the question, and doing a 10-fold cross-validation would look like this:

   ```
   all.task <- TaskClassif$new("all.data", data, target = "diabetes")
   rr = resample(all.task, elearner, rsmp("cv"))  # will take some time
   rr$aggregate(msr("classif.auc"))
   #> classif.auc 
   #>   0.9366438
   ```
2. I have shown how to construct the graph using the `po("select")` `PipeOp`s, because it is fully general: You can choose to have some feature both in the `glmnet_lrn` `Learner`, as well as in the `log_reg_lrn` directly, by playing around with the `selector` values. If all you want to do is really to "divert" a feature from a single operation, you can also use the `affect_columns` to a `Selector` that selects the column you want. The following creates a (linear) graph that does exactly the same, but is less flexible:

   ```
   glmnet_cv1_nosuperdoc = po("learner_cv", glmnet_lrn, id = "glmnet",
     affect_columns = selector_invert(selector_name("superdoc")))
   ensemble2 = glmnet_cv1_nosuperdoc %>>% log_reg_lrn
   e2learner = as_learner(ensemble2)
   # etc.
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this marvellous solution including cv. The `mlr3` package familiy is very helpful. I read that `classif.cv_glmnet` does an internal 10-fold CV optimization. Can this somehow be repeated (`repeatedcv`) within the solution you proposed  (as in my `caret::trainControl` approach)  to [avoid variability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079660/extract-the-coefficients-for-the-best-tuning-parameters-of-a-glmnet-model-in-car) in smaller data sets? I think tuning both, alpha and lambda using `mlr3` is not (yet) possible?

Comment: AIUI your caret code essentially does hyperparameter tuning integrated to the glmnet learner. With mlr3, you would use [`AutoTuner`](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/tuning.html#autotuner), which wraps a learner and tunes it internally. You can specify to use `rsmp("repeated_cv")` (does 10 reps 10 folds by default). Caret's default tuner seems to be equivalent to mlr3 `tnr("grid_search", resolution = 3)` (but consider using random search). Note that `po("learner_cv")` *also* does another CV: to give out-of-fold predictions for unbiased training of the `"classif.log_reg"` (unrelated to tuning).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Pat-s [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800689/tuning-glmnet-using-mlr3) not to tune `cv.glmnet` in `mlr3`. Holds that true for my question? Since this problem is not really part of my initial question, I opened a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696405/how-to-repeat-cv-glmnet-in-mlr3)

Comment: It is a complicated story. Pat-s is right in that cvglmnet tunes the `lambda`/`s` parameter internally. AFAIK it does not tune `alpha`. So I think you could tune `alpha` and `lambda` using `glmnet` (which I think didn't exist in mlr3 one year ago when that Q was asked), or you could alternatively tune just `alpha` on `cvglmnet` (which does its own tuning of lambda internally). These are both not ideal solutions (cvglmnet makes some optimizations that glmnet doesn't, but OTOH this nests CV twice and can't do repcv AFAIK). I don't know glmnet well enough to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks to your comments I could solve my [question related to variability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66727339/repeated-cv-in-a-mrl3-ensemble-model/66737630#66737630)