# Repeated cv in a mrl3 ensemble model

Tags: r, mlr3

I have a beautiful `mlr3` ensemble model (combined `glmnet` and `glm`) for binary prediction, see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644375/two-level-stacked-learner-enseble-model-combining-elastic-net-and-logistic-reg)

```
library("mlr3verse")
library("dplyr")

# get example data
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes, package="mlbench")
data <- PimaIndiansDiabetes

# add an additional predictor "superdoc" which is not entered in the glmnet but in the final glm
set.seed(2323)
data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(superdoc=case_when(diabetes=="pos" ~ as.numeric(sample(0:2,1)), TRUE~ 0)) %>% 
  ungroup -> data

# make a rather small train set
set.seed(23)
test.data <- sample_n(data,70,replace=FALSE)

# creat elastic net regression
glmnet_lrn = lrn("classif.cv_glmnet", predict_type = "prob")

# create the learner out-of-bag predictions
glmnet_cv1 = po("learner_cv", glmnet_lrn, id = "glmnet")

# PipeOp that drops 'superdoc', i.e. selects all except 'superdoc'
# (ID given to avoid ID clash with other selector)
drop_superdoc = po("select", id = "drop.superdoc",
                   selector = selector_invert(selector_name("superdoc")))

# PipeOp that selects 'superdoc' (and drops all other columns)
select_superdoc = po("select", id = "select.superdoc",
                     selector = selector_name("superdoc"))

# superdoc along one path, the fitted model along the other
stacking_layer = gunion(list(
  select_superdoc,
  drop_superdoc %>>% glmnet_cv1
)) %>>% po("featureunion", id = "union1")

# final logistic regression
log_reg_lrn = lrn("classif.log_reg", predict_type = "prob")

# combine ensemble model
ensemble = stacking_layer %>>% log_reg_lrn


#define tests
train.task <- TaskClassif$new("test.data", test.data, target = "diabetes")

# make ensemble learner
elearner = as_learner(ensemble)
```

```r
ensemble$plot(html = FALSE)
```

[image]

If I train it with different set.seed, I get different coefficients.
I think this is mainly caused by the [rather low number of training data that is entered in the glmnet model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079660/extract-the-coefficients-for-the-best-tuning-parameters-of-a-glmnet-model-in-car) and could be migitated by repeated cross-validation.

```
# Train the Learner:
# seed 1
elearner = as_learner(ensemble)
set.seed(22521136)
elearner$train(train.task) -> seed1

# seed 2
elearner = as_learner(ensemble)
set.seed(12354)
elearner$train(train.task) -> seed2

# different coefficients of the glment  model
coef(seed1$model$glmnet$model, s ="lambda.min")
#> 9 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>                        1
#> (Intercept) -6.238598277
#> age          .          
#> glucose      0.023462376
#> insulin     -0.001007037
#> mass         0.055587740
#> pedigree     0.322911217
#> pregnant     0.137419564
#> pressure     .          
#> triceps      .
coef(seed2$model$glmnet$model, s ="lambda.min")
#> 9 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>                        1
#> (Intercept) -6.876802620
#> age          .          
#> glucose      0.025601712
#> insulin     -0.001500856
#> mass         0.063029550
#> pedigree     0.464369417
#> pregnant     0.155971123
#> pressure     .          
#> triceps      .

# different coefficients of the final regression model
seed1$model$classif.log_reg$model$coefficients
#>     (Intercept)        superdoc glmnet.prob.neg glmnet.prob.pos 
#>       -9.438452       23.710923        8.726956              NA
seed2$model$classif.log_reg$model$coefficients
#>     (Intercept)        superdoc glmnet.prob.neg glmnet.prob.pos 
#>       0.3698143      23.5362542      -5.5514365              NA
```

### Question:

Where and how could a repeated cross-validation be entered in my `mlr3` ensemble model to migitate these varying results? Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: you are not tuning anything apart the inner tuning performed by `glment.cv`, See https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/tuning.html. In tuning you can specify the tuner, measures and resampling strategy for the mlr3 learner (it can be an ensemble). However `glment.cv` performs cv independently of this, and I am pretty sure you can not specify repeated cv in it. Instead of calling `glmnet.cv` you can call [`lrn("classif.glmnet")`](https://mlr3learners.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_learners_classif.glmnet.html) and tune like any other mlr3 learner.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not sure how to combine an AutoTuner `at =AutoTuner$new(
  learner = lrn("classif.glmnet",  rsmp("repeated_cv") ... )`  with the correct PipeOp. Would `po("learner_cv", at, id="glmnet))` be correct?. Would I not need something like  `po("learner_repeated_cv", ..)` ?

Comment: the learner is `elearner` after `as_learner(ensemble)`. You should definitely read chapters 1 - 5 in the ml3 book first and then try to use mlr3.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I read the `mlr3` book before I started to use `mlr3`. However, not all concepts are easy to undertand (especially for people who used `caret`, not `mlr` in the past), this is why I asked this question. Think I have to start reading `mlr` first and hope for some support on stack for my early stages in `mlr3`. Nevertheless, `mlr3` has already [my](https://github.com/sponsors/mlr-org) support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to missuse's comment, his marvellous tutorial ([Tuning a stacked learner](https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/posts/2020-04-27-tuning-stacking/)) and mb706's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644375/two-level-stacked-learner-enseble-model-combining-elastic-net-and-logistic-reg/66665277?noredirect=1#comment117936042_66665277) I think I could solve my question.

Replace `"classif.cv_glmnet"` with `"classif.glmnet"`

```
# Add tuning

resampling = rsmp("repeated_cv")
resampling$param_set$values = list(repeats = 10, folds=5)


ps_ens = ParamSet$new(
  list(
    ParamDbl$new("glmnet.alpha", 0, 1),
    ParamDbl$new("glmnet.s", 0, 1)))

auto1 = AutoTuner$new(
  learner = elearner,
  resampling = resampling,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  search_space = ps_ens,
  terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 5), # to limit running time
  tuner = tnr("random_search")
)
```

Train with different `set.seed` and get same coefficients

```
# Train with different set.seed

#first
set.seed(22521136)
at1= auto1
at1$train(train.task) -> seed1

# second
set.seed(12354)
at2= auto1
at2$train(train.task) -> seed2


# Compare coefficients of the learners

# classif.log_reg
seed1$model$learner$model$classif.log_reg$model$coefficients
# (Intercept)        superdoc glmnet.prob.neg glmnet.prob.pos 
# 2.467855       21.570766       -6.966693              NA


seed2$model$learner$model$classif.log_reg$model$coefficients
# (Intercept)        superdoc glmnet.prob.neg glmnet.prob.pos 
# 2.467855       21.570766       -6.966693              NA


#classif.glmnet
coef(at1$learner$model$glmnet$model, alpha=at1$tuning_result$glmnet.alpha,s=at1$tuning_result$glmnet.s)
# 9 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# 1
# (Intercept) -3.3066981659
# age          0.0076392198
# glucose      0.0077516975
# insulin      0.0003389759
# mass         0.0133955320
# pedigree     0.3256754612
# pregnant     0.0686746156
# pressure     0.0081338885
# triceps     -0.0054976030

coef(at2$learner$model$glmnet$model, alpha=at2$tuning_result$glmnet.alpha,s=at2$tuning_result$glmnet.s)
# 9 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# 1
# (Intercept) -3.3066981659
# age          0.0076392198
# glucose      0.0077516975
# insulin      0.0003389759
# mass         0.0133955320
# pedigree     0.3256754612
# pregnant     0.0686746156
# pressure     0.0081338885
# triceps     -0.0054976030
```